# When does the serial-voting reverse process happen?

Tags: support, serial-voting

I've been hit with several serial votes and I'm wondering how soon they will be reversed, since I've noticed it used to happen in the past.

---

The specific site is Code Golf. See the picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The automatic serial voting detection script runs daily at 3am UTC.